# Searching for data in arrays [Node.JS]

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, search, find

I have a question:
(sorry for the bad formatting)

I have an array:

```
[
    {
        "data": [
            [
                "kek",
                "lol"
            ],
            [
                "notkek",
                "notlol"
            ]
        ]
    }
]
```

If someone writes "kek" it should search it in the "data" array and return the "kek" position inside its array
 (`["kek","lol"]`)

and its array position

```
{
    "data": [
        [
            "kek",
            "lol"
         ]}
```

(in this case "data[0]")

If anybody knows the answer, please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `Array.findIndex` and `Array.includes` may help you

```js
const obj = {
  data: [
    [
      'kek',
      'lol'
    ],
    [
      'notkek',
      'notlol'
    ],
  ],
};

const keyToSearch = 'kek';

// We look for the key
const index = obj.data.findIndex(x => x.includes(keyToSearch));

if (index === -1) {
  console.log(`We didn't found ${keyToSearch}`);
} else {
  console.log(`We found ${keyToSearch} at index ${index}`);
}
```

---

**Double index recuperation**

```js
const obj = {
  data: [
    [
      'kek',
      'lol'
    ],
    [
      'notkek',
      'notlol'
    ],
    [
      'notkek',
      'notlol',
      'otherstuff',
      'kek',
      'test',
    ],
  ],
};

const keyToSearch = 'kek';

const ret = obj.data.reduce((tmp, x, xi) => {
  // We look for the key
  const index = x.findIndex(y => y === keyToSearch);

  if (index === -1) return tmp;

  return [
    ...tmp,

    {
      absoluteIndex: xi,
      relativeIndex: index,
    },
  ];
}, []);


if (!ret.length) {
  console.log(`We didn't found ${keyToSearch}`);
} else {
  ret.forEach(({
    absoluteIndex,
    relativeIndex,
  }) => console.log(
    `We found ${keyToSearch} at`,
    `data index ${absoluteIndex}, in ${relativeIndex} position`,
  ));
}
```

Comment: but what if I need to find not only index of query inside the big array, but also in this array `[
      'kek',
      'lol'
    ]`
so If it found the index in big array also search in the array that it found (for examle "kek" is at index 0 at smaller array)

Comment: I've made an edit, where you can extract in which data index the key is and in which position

Answer (score 0):

```
userInput = 'kek'
  let item = data.map((item, indx) => {
     item.includes(userInput) ? return({"indx":indx,"nestedIndex":item.indexOf(userInput)}) : null
   })
```

map over the data array and if the nested array had the item your searching for than return the index of the array and the index of the item with in that array